# Indexed pages redirection to single page app: keep place in google search

Tags: redirect, seo, single-page-application

I have old site with thousands of indexed pages which rendered on server side and have different URLs.

```
my.site/pages/1
my.site/pages/2
the lot of pages...
```

I developed single page application with client-side routing.

```
my.site#pages/1
my.site#pages/2
the lot of pages...
```

Google today supports and indexes client-side rendering and recommend for developers create reach UI apps with client-side rendering and other features.

But what can really happens when i'll redirect with 301 all my thousands of indexed pages to single app page?

```
my.site#pages/...the thousands of pages
```

How to react Google to this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Rewrote a huge site with about 1 million pages in Angular... I might have google send users to server rendered pages which use javascript to redirect users to the single page app... not sure if it's ideal. I didn't want to use URL_Fragements, and I wanted shareable links to show up on facebook preview too - and some client side CORS apis and local storage data made me not want to try using angular universal... Let me know if you find a nice solution.